# Android: How to add battery stats to stock lock screen while not charging?

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

The stock Android lock screen will display your battery status while your phone is charging; does anyone know how to have it display your current battery status while it is not charging?

This doesn't seems like a super difficult task to accomplish, I'm just unsure where I need to start to get things going. It would be so awesome if someone would actually help me.

Comment: The lock screen is part of the Android firmware, and can only be modified by modifying the firmware itself.

Comment: So, are you saying it cannot be done or were you just being informative? People have added music controls to the lock screen, why not a battery status?

Comment: Yep. good idea. if you find any method easy to apply. I want to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the source of myLock for Android. Even though the source is not linked on the Google code page (why?) it is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/source/browse/) under the terms of the GPLv3.